# SyntaxError: missing ] after element list ([object Object])

Tags: css, json, eval

I return JSON from PHP, it works fine,
but when the data is empty i fill in default JSON data, to use for applying .css on a jQuery selected element, like this:

```
db.data = { "blocks" :  {"css" : {"background-color" : "purple" }}};
```

(Edit: the css from my db actually contains slashes and does work with the eval() : `"css":"{ \"background-color\" : \"grey\" }` )

If I console.log it, FF will display it as an object (all green and red and nicely formatted and clickable/expandable in firebug:

```
Object { background-color= "purple" }
```

I `eval()` it before passing it to css.
I tried `$.evalJSON` from the jQuery JSON Plugin, but it will give:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
```

Edit: I tried it without eval() but will throw the same error, but not when I use the css with the slashes

I tried manually adding a `]` somewhere, but obviously wont work, and if I add two, it will create an array, which I don't want.

I apply CSS to element like this:

```
DOMID = $('#target');
var CSS = eval(" (" +db.data.blocks.css+") ");
this.DOMID.css(CSS);
```

Tried without the `" ("`, without spaces, `"("`.

any ideas?

Comment: The reason `var CSS = eval(" (" +db.data.blocks.css+") ");` doesn't work is because your object is [correctly] using double-quotes and `eval()` gets confused. But @Jon has the solution. `eval` is evil.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted would never work because it is misguided. There is no need to `eval` anything, and even if there were coercing `db.data.blocks.css` to a string (in order to put in the parens) would give you back the completely wrong value.

Instead, you should simply write

```
this.DOMID.css(db.data.blocks.css);
```

Comment: Strangely that will still throw the same "SyntaxError: missing ] after element list" and if I don't eval() it, the ajax JSON won't work, because for some reason it returns as a string from the db

Comment: but that's probably because of the slashes ("css":"{ \"background-color\" : \"grey\" })

Comment: @TrySpace: Then the code you post is different than what you describe. Fix either one or the other :)

Comment: no, that is the json that actually works, that is returned from the DB/PHP

Comment: @TrySpace: The question does not have **any** JSON in it. JSON (e.g. `"{ \"foo\": 42 }"`) is not the same as a JS object literal (e.g. `{ foo: 42 }`).

Comment: Yes, but my css works with the slashes, I admit, the slashes should not be there, but that's a different problem, without the eval() the purple css still doesn't work, while it should, I also don't understand, but your solution doesn't work

Comment: { "blocks" :  {"css" : {"background-color" : "purple" }}} IS actually JSON btw.